# Complex integer arithmetic in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, integer, multiplication, complextype

I got a little problem with following MATLAB code:

```
obj.valueH = vectorValue(obj.E) / Z0;
obj.H = obj.vH * obj.valueH;
```

Those are values for variables used in that code:

```
                 E: [2.4431 +12.0558i 0 3.8736e-016 +3.4863e-016i]
                vH: [0 1 0]
            valueH: 0.0065 + 0.0320i
                Z0: 376.7303
vectorValue(obj.E): 2.4431 +12.0558i
```

Unfortunately instead of simple vH and valueH multiplication I get following error:

```
??? Error using ==> mtimes
Complex integer arithmetic is not supported.

Error in ==> point>point.point at 39
        obj.H = obj.vH * obj.valueH;
```

May I kindly ask you for an explanation what is wrong?

Comment: convert `vH` to `double` type: `obj.H = double( obj.vH ) * obj.valueH;`

Comment: @Shai: this has always mistified me...Do you know why MATLAB *downcasts* by default? In C-family languages, *upcasting* is the default, which IMHO makes a lot more sense in most cases...

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis interesting observation. My guess is that while most languages try to maintain close porximity to the actual procesing going on in the machine, Matlab tries to mask the actual computation and encourage the programer to focus on the algorithmic/mathematical level. Therefore, the defualt data type for most languages is the `int` whereas for Matlab is the `double`.

Comment: @Shai: If you have some long calculation involving only `double`s, but *one* `int8`, *everything* will be cast to `int8` prior to the calculation. This often results in results that force you to worry about the actual computation rather than the mathematics; quite the opposite behavior. In all other languages that I know, the `int8` will be *upcast* to `double` prior to the calculations...in general, the most "advanced" datatype of any value involved in the calculation will be used to cast all other values to. In MATLAB, everything is cast to the most *primitive* datatype.

Comment: @Shai: This has been the cause of quite a few SO questions actually...which sort of indicates that people do not expect this. Can you find anything that mentioned *why* TMW ever decided to go down this path?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis - I'm afraid I am not that familiar with this subject. TMW sometimes do very wierd things...